# What is the meaning of speed is good in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

I saw an advertisement of a telecom company which says:

> speed is good

What is the meaning of speed is good? Is it a habitual action like speed is always good? Or they are talking about their internet speed? But if they are talking about their speed, shouldn't they have said The speed is good. Right?

Comment: They are making a universal generalization about "speed" and trusting that the audience will concur, and that the audience will infer that the company's network transmission is speedy.

Comment: Are they talking about their speed or speed in general. (Like speed is always good)

Answer (score 1):

"The speed is good." may be grammatically correct, but less colloquial. My guess is the ad sought to take on a conversational or colloquial tone. For example, if a friend of mine told me "I just got a new internet connection and the speed is way better than my previous one!" I might reply, "Speed is good!"

You're right that in this context, a few other words might be implied, such as "Speed is (always) good." or "(Internet) speed is (a) good (thing to have)."